# How to understand this simultaneous assignment evaluation in python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I have recently started learning python. I was playing around with simultaneous assignments today and came across some results that were produced by my code that I cannot understand.

```py
x, y = 3, 5
x, y = y, (x+y)
print(y)
```

The output is **8**.

I am not understanding why `y = 8` instead of `y = 10` despite `x = y = 5` being evaluated first. Since `y = 8`, this tell us that `x = 3` when `y = x + y` is being evaluated ? How is that possible if `x = y` is first evaluated, since it is evaluated left to right ?

I first debugged the code (which produced the same result), which I cannot understand. I also have tried looking at the python documentation, where it states "simultaneous overlaps within the collection of assigned-to variables occur left-to-right, sometimes resulting in confusion." 
The example that it presents follows my logic:

```
x = [0, 1]
i = 0
i, x[i] = 1, 2         
print(x)
```

It outputs **2**.

(Evaluated left to right) Since i is updated to 1. Then, this updated i is used and hence, `x[1] = 2` not `x[0] = 2`.

I really would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 3):

> I am not understanding why `y = 8` instead of `y = 10` despite `x = y = 5` being evaluated first

The right side of an assignment is evaluated first.

In your assignment with `x = 3` and `y = 5`

```
x, y = y, (x+y)
```

the right side is evaluated to a tuple `(5, 8)` first and then assigned to the values on the left side. Therefore y is **8**.

You could also think of it as

```
x, y = 3, 5
temp = y, x + y
x, y = temp
```

To see what really happens internal, you can disassemble your code:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(x, y):
...     x, y = y, x + y
...
>>> dis.dis(f)
```

Outputs

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              2 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              4 LOAD_FAST                1 (y)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              8 ROT_TWO
             10 STORE_FAST               0 (x)
             12 STORE_FAST               1 (y)
             14 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see, the addition is performed before the assignment.

Comment: You did a better job explaining this than me. Props for using the disassemble-module

Answer (score 0):

Python goes right-to-left, left-to-right. You can imagine that python pushes its operations to a stack-like data structure.

Looking at the first assignment: `x, y = 3, 5`

1. python will first push the right-hand side value onto the stack as a tuple.
2. run an unpacking-sequence for *n* values from the stack, and puts the values back onto the stack right-to-left. "push 5 to the stack, then 3". Current stack = [3, 5]
3. Finished with the right-hand side, python will assign values to the left-hand side left-to-right, while removing top-of-stack. So it will first tak 3 and store it in variable x, then 5 and store it in variable y.

You can inspect the operations python does in byte code using the **dis** module.

[image: python byte-code for assignment x, y = 3, 5]

The following assignments:

```
x, y = 3, 5
x, y = y, (x + y)
```

Produce the following operations:

[image: left to right assignment operations]

You can inspect the bytecode operations here: http://pyspanishdoc.sourceforge.net/lib/bytecodes.html